# XSLT Looping through nested elements with conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I loop though XML and look at all child elements when the parent also has multiple elements.

I am trying to use a when that looks like

```
<xsl:when test="ROOT/PARENT[CHILD/@value] &lt;= 9999">
```

This is only giving me the first child value from the first parent. How can I loop through all the parents in a when statement?

XML example:

```
<ROOT>
<PARENT>
    <CHILD value="1">
    </CHILD>
</PARENT>
<PARENT>
    <CHILD value="2">
    </CHILD>
</PARENT>
<PARENT>
    <CHILD value="3">
    </CHILD>
</PARENT>
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of options to do it. One option is to use nested `for-each` loops to iterate on `<PARENT>` and `<CHILD>`.

```
<xsl:template match="ROOT">
    <xsl:for-each select="PARENT">
        <PARENT>
            <xsl:for-each select="CHILD[@value &lt; 9999]">
                <CHILD_VALUE><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></CHILD_VALUE>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </PARENT>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Other option is to match the `<PARENT>` template and use a `for-each` loop on the `<CHILD>` within the template

```
<xsl:template match="PARENT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="CHILD[@value &lt; 9999]">
            <CHILD_VALUE><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></CHILD_VALUE>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If we modify the input XML to include multiple `<CHILD>` elements within the `<PARENT>` as below

```
<ROOT>
    <PARENT>
        <CHILD value="1"></CHILD>
        <CHILD value="11"></CHILD>
        <CHILD value="12"></CHILD>
    </PARENT>
    <PARENT>
        <CHILD value="2"></CHILD>
        <CHILD value="21"></CHILD>
        <CHILD value="22"></CHILD>
    </PARENT>
    <PARENT>
        <CHILD value="3"></CHILD>
        <CHILD value="31"></CHILD>
        <CHILD value="32"></CHILD>
    </PARENT>
</ROOT>
```

both the XSLT templates, give the below output.

```
<PARENT>
    <CHILD_VALUE>1</CHILD_VALUE>
    <CHILD_VALUE>11</CHILD_VALUE>
    <CHILD_VALUE>12</CHILD_VALUE>
</PARENT>
<PARENT>
    <CHILD_VALUE>2</CHILD_VALUE>
    <CHILD_VALUE>21</CHILD_VALUE>
    <CHILD_VALUE>22</CHILD_VALUE>
</PARENT>
<PARENT>
    <CHILD_VALUE>3</CHILD_VALUE>
    <CHILD_VALUE>31</CHILD_VALUE>
    <CHILD_VALUE>32</CHILD_VALUE>
</PARENT>
```

Comment: In the nested for loop is there a way to say that we only want to check that until it happens after that we do not care to check it any more? So as soon as the child has a value less than 9999 we do something and we do not do that something again?

Comment: XSLT does not behave like other programming languages. So if you are thinking of breaking the loop once a condition is met and moving to next, it won't happen. XSLT will be transforming the XML in one pass so whatever logic is needed has to be applied using multiple conditions. It would be better if you can explain the required scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop over all `PARENT` elements with a `CHILD` element with an attribute `value` smaller than 9999.

```
<xsl:for-each select="ROOT/PARENT[CHILD/@value &lt; 9999]">
   <!-- do something-->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: That seems to loop through all the child elements that are in the first parent. This is not looping through all the parents for me.